# Using information_schema.COLUMNS in select search

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to select all columns except one, so I'm using this:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from information_schema.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='report' and COLUMN_NAME != 'date';
```

It returns me the correct result, but when I try to apply it using:

```
select 
(
 select COLUMN_NAME 
 from information_schema.COLUMNS 
 where TABLE_NAME='report' and COLUMN_NAME != 'date'
) 
from report limit 1;
```

It gives an error of `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`

I tried to group_concat it but it returns just the columns (query):

```
select 
(
 select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) 
 from information_schema.COLUMNS 
 where TABLE_NAME='report' and COLUMN_NAME != 'date'
) 
from risk_assessment.report limit 1;

| (select group_concat(COLUMN_NAME) from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='report' and COLUMN_NAME != 'date')                                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id,ref,creator,status,username,title,site,location,comment,id,status,type,chemical_name,description,title,creator,frequency,location,form,storage,comments,comments_tick,username |
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntax for that in MariaDB. You cannot do something like (select * except x from table) in a single statement.

However, you can do it via few steps:

```
SET @sql = 
    CONCAT('SELECT ',
            (SELECT 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
                FROM
                    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = '<schema>'
                    AND TABLE_NAME = '<table>'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('<column>')),
            ' FROM <table>');
PREPARE s FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s;
```